# Multiple updates of attributes in BaseX

Tags: svg, xquery, basex, xquery-update

I'm trying to update a few attributes of a SVG tag in in a Xquery function in BaseX. So far I managed to update one attribute and returning the new node but not multiple attributes.

I tried multiple updates as a variation of the statement described [here](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update#update) but whatever I tried it wouldn't work.

```
declare function  page:scaleSVG ($svg as node()*, $scale as xs:integer) as  node()* {
  return // update a few values of $svg attributes and return it
};
```

The function above is basically what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the copy/modify/return construction. Here's an example:

```
declare function page:scaleSVG ($svg as node()*, $scale as xs:integer) as  node()* {
copy $c := $svg
 modify (
    replace value of node $c/@width with $scale,
    replace value of node $c/@height with $scale 
 )
return $c
};
```

Then calling this:

```
page:scaleSVG(<svg width="100" height="100" />, 200)
```

will return this:

```
<svg width="200" height="200"/>
```